# What does three small rings in a triangle mean in a Swedish parish registers?

Tags: 19th-century, 18th-century, parish-register, sweden

In Sweden during the 18th and 19th century each parish had a "Husförhörslängd", a book tallying the people in the parish keeping track of how well they knew their biblical history, and if they had taken their communion.

Very often in these books I find that some people have a marking of three small rings in a triangle. See enclosed picture.

What does this marking mean?

[image: Example of three rings marking]

Comment: It might have to do with the Trinity.

Comment: @Luke Possible: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shield_of_the_Trinity

Comment: @Luke though it appears on some and not others, so even if it does symbolize the Trinity it probably has more meaning such as "they completed these sacraments" or something

Comment: What do the headings mean?

Comment: Is it correct that _Omstandigheter_ in the heading means "circumstances", making this column a general collection of other relevant information?

Comment: @Fortiter: Correct. It's used like we today would use a "Notes" column. The other columns are about where you moved inf from (and too, but they are outside the picture) and if you can read, and how well you understand the bible.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I happened on the answer:

[image: signs]

Turns out it means the person has been vaccinated against smallpox, either by vaccine, or by "protective pox", which I think means cowpox.

Comment: Good question; great answer. Thank you Lennart

Comment: So does the + (for Smittkoppor) indicate that the person died of smallpox or that they survived the disease?

Comment: @Fortiter: That they survived, at least in the cases I've seen.